# r - Generating cumulative sum, total sum, and unique identifiers between start and end dates

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

## What I want to do

I have a dataset of protest events in the United States. Some events are stand-alone events, while others persist day-after-day (a "multi-day event"). My dataset is structured at the daily level, so a three-day multi-day event is spread out over three rows.

I want to accomplish the following:

1. Create a cumulative sum of the number of days thus far in any given multi-day event. Specifically, I want to count the number of days **between the "First day" and "Last day"** of any linked event.
2. Put the total number of days of each multi-event as a variable
3. "Name" each multi-day event by concatenating the state in which the protest occurred and a sequential identity number starting at 1 in each state and extending upwards.

## Data

Here's a reproducible example:

```
# Library
library(tidyverse) # Brings in dplyr

# Generate the data set of protests
test <- data.frame(state = c(rep("Washington", 10), rep("Idaho", 10)),
                   date = lubridate::ymd(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-10", "2021-01-15", 
                            "2021-01-16", "2021-01-17", "2021-01-18", "2021-01-19", "2021-01-28",
                            "2021-01-12", "2021-01-13", "2021-01-14", "2021-02-01", "2021-02-03",
                            "2021-02-04", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-08", "2021-02-10", "2021-02-14")))

# Now create some lags and leads
test <- test %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(date_lag = lag(date),
         date_lead = lead(date),
         days_last = date - date_lag,
         days_next = date_lead - date,
         link_last = if_else(days_last <= 1, 1, 0),
         link_next = if_else(days_next <= 1, 1, 0),
         sequence = if_else(link_last == 0 & link_next == 1, "First day",
                            if_else(is.na(link_last) == TRUE & link_next == 1, "First day",
                                    if_else(link_last == 1 & link_next == 1, "Ongoing",
                                            if_else(link_last == 1 & link_next == 0, "Last day", 
                                                    if_else(link_last == 1 & is.na(link_next)==TRUE, "Last day", "Not linked"))))))
```

This generates the following dataframe:

```
   state      date       date_lag   date_lead  days_last days_next link_last link_next sequence  
   <chr>      <date>     <date>     <date>     <drtn>    <drtn>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>     
 1 Washington 2021-01-01 NA         2021-01-03 NA days    2 days          NA         0 NA        
 2 Washington 2021-01-03 2021-01-01 2021-01-04  2 days    1 days           0         1 First day 
 3 Washington 2021-01-04 2021-01-03 2021-01-10  1 days    6 days           1         0 Last day  
 4 Washington 2021-01-10 2021-01-04 2021-01-15  6 days    5 days           0         0 Not linked
 5 Washington 2021-01-15 2021-01-10 2021-01-16  5 days    1 days           0         1 First day 
 6 Washington 2021-01-16 2021-01-15 2021-01-17  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing   
 7 Washington 2021-01-17 2021-01-16 2021-01-18  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing   
 8 Washington 2021-01-18 2021-01-17 2021-01-19  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing   
 9 Washington 2021-01-19 2021-01-18 2021-01-28  1 days    9 days           1         0 Last day  
10 Washington 2021-01-28 2021-01-19 NA          9 days   NA days           0        NA NA        
11 Idaho      2021-01-12 NA         2021-01-13 NA days    1 days          NA         1 NA        
12 Idaho      2021-01-13 2021-01-12 2021-01-14  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing   
13 Idaho      2021-01-14 2021-01-13 2021-02-01  1 days   18 days           1         0 Last day  
14 Idaho      2021-02-01 2021-01-14 2021-02-03 18 days    2 days           0         0 Not linked
15 Idaho      2021-02-03 2021-02-01 2021-02-04  2 days    1 days           0         1 First day 
16 Idaho      2021-02-04 2021-02-03 2021-02-05  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing   
17 Idaho      2021-02-05 2021-02-04 2021-02-08  1 days    3 days           1         0 Last day  
18 Idaho      2021-02-08 2021-02-05 2021-02-10  3 days    2 days           0         0 Not linked
19 Idaho      2021-02-10 2021-02-08 2021-02-14  2 days    4 days           0         0 Not linked
20 Idaho      2021-02-14 2021-02-10 NA          4 days   NA days           0        NA NA
```

### What I want to create:

```
   state      date       date_lag   date_lead  days_last days_next link_last link_next sequence   cumulative duration name        
   <chr>      <date>     <date>     <date>     <drtn>    <drtn>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       
 1 Washington 2021-01-01 NA         2021-01-03 NA days    2 days          NA         0 NA                 NA        0 NA          
 2 Washington 2021-01-03 2021-01-01 2021-01-04  2 days    1 days           0         1 First day           1        2 Washington.1
 3 Washington 2021-01-04 2021-01-03 2021-01-10  1 days    6 days           1         0 Last day            2        2 Washington.1
 4 Washington 2021-01-10 2021-01-04 2021-01-15  6 days    5 days           0         0 Not linked         NA        0 NA          
 5 Washington 2021-01-15 2021-01-10 2021-01-16  5 days    1 days           0         1 First day           1        5 Washington.2
 6 Washington 2021-01-16 2021-01-15 2021-01-17  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing             2        5 Washington.2
 7 Washington 2021-01-17 2021-01-16 2021-01-18  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing             3        5 Washington.2
 8 Washington 2021-01-18 2021-01-17 2021-01-19  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing             4        5 Washington.2
 9 Washington 2021-01-19 2021-01-18 2021-01-28  1 days    9 days           1         0 Last day            5        5 Washington.2
10 Washington 2021-01-28 2021-01-19 NA          9 days   NA days           0        NA NA                 NA       NA NA          
11 Idaho      2021-01-12 NA         2021-01-13 NA days    1 days          NA         1 NA                  1        3 Idaho.1     
12 Idaho      2021-01-13 2021-01-12 2021-01-14  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing             2        3 Idaho.1     
13 Idaho      2021-01-14 2021-01-13 2021-02-01  1 days   18 days           1         0 Last day            3        3 Idaho.1     
14 Idaho      2021-02-01 2021-01-14 2021-02-03 18 days    2 days           0         0 Not linked         NA       NA NA          
15 Idaho      2021-02-03 2021-02-01 2021-02-04  2 days    1 days           0         1 First day           1        3 Idaho.2     
16 Idaho      2021-02-04 2021-02-03 2021-02-05  1 days    1 days           1         1 Ongoing             2        3 Idaho.2     
17 Idaho      2021-02-05 2021-02-04 2021-02-08  1 days    3 days           1         0 Last day            3        3 Idaho.2     
18 Idaho      2021-02-08 2021-02-05 2021-02-10  3 days    2 days           0         0 Not linked         NA       NA NA          
19 Idaho      2021-02-10 2021-02-08 2021-02-14  2 days    4 days           0         0 Not linked         NA       NA NA          
20 Idaho      2021-02-14 2021-02-10 NA          4 days   NA days           0        NA NA                 NA       NA NA
```

**Side question**: Why is test$sequence[11] an NA and not "First day"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure these are the specific numbers you're looking for, but this represents what seems to me a simpler and more idiomatic tidyverse approach:

```
test %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(days_last = as.numeric(date - lag(date)),
         new_section = 1*(is.na(days_last) | days_last > 1),   # EDIT
         section = cumsum(new_section),
         name = paste(state,section, sep = ".")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(duration = as.numeric(max(date) - min(date) + 1),
     sequence = case_when(duration == 1 ~ "Unlinked",
                          row_number() == 1 ~ "First Day",
                          row_number() == n() ~ "Last Day",
                          TRUE ~ "Ongoing")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Here, I mark any gap of more than one day as a new event, take the cumulative sum, and use that to define the duration of each event.

```
# A tibble: 20 x 8
   state      date       days_last new_section section name         duration sequence 
   <chr>      <date>         <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <chr>    
 1 Washington 2021-01-01        NA           1       1 Washington.1        1 Unlinked 
 2 Washington 2021-01-03         2           1       2 Washington.2        2 First Day
 3 Washington 2021-01-04         1           0       2 Washington.2        2 Last Day 
 4 Washington 2021-01-10         6           1       3 Washington.3        1 Unlinked 
 5 Washington 2021-01-15         5           1       4 Washington.4        5 First Day
 6 Washington 2021-01-16         1           0       4 Washington.4        5 Ongoing  
 7 Washington 2021-01-17         1           0       4 Washington.4        5 Ongoing  
 8 Washington 2021-01-18         1           0       4 Washington.4        5 Ongoing  
 9 Washington 2021-01-19         1           0       4 Washington.4        5 Last Day 
10 Washington 2021-01-28         9           1       5 Washington.5        1 Unlinked 
11 Idaho      2021-01-12        NA           1       1 Idaho.1             3 First Day
12 Idaho      2021-01-13         1           0       1 Idaho.1             3 Ongoing  
13 Idaho      2021-01-14         1           0       1 Idaho.1             3 Last Day 
14 Idaho      2021-02-01        18           1       2 Idaho.2             1 Unlinked 
15 Idaho      2021-02-03         2           1       3 Idaho.3             3 First Day
16 Idaho      2021-02-04         1           0       3 Idaho.3             3 Ongoing  
17 Idaho      2021-02-05         1           0       3 Idaho.3             3 Last Day 
18 Idaho      2021-02-08         3           1       4 Idaho.4             1 Unlinked 
19 Idaho      2021-02-10         2           1       5 Idaho.5             1 Unlinked 
20 Idaho      2021-02-14         4           1       6 Idaho.6             1 Unlinked
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I think creating specific functions to do the counting is easier than try to do everything in a single pipe.

I left all the intermediate steps and the intermediate columns in the output so you can see what each step is doing. It's very likely you won't need to keep all these columns and you probably can simplify the steps once you understand the approach.

```r
library(tidyverse) # Brings in dplyr

# Generate the data set of protests
test <- data.frame(state = c(rep("Washington", 10), rep("Idaho", 10)),
                   date = lubridate::ymd(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-10", "2021-01-15", 
                                           "2021-01-16", "2021-01-17", "2021-01-18", "2021-01-19", "2021-01-28",
                                           "2021-01-12", "2021-01-13", "2021-01-14", "2021-02-01", "2021-02-03",
                                           "2021-02-04", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-08", "2021-02-10", "2021-02-14")))

event_count <- function(v){
  cnt <- 0
  result <- integer(length(v))
  for(idx in seq_along(v)) {
    if(v[idx]) {
      cnt <- 0
    } else {
      cnt <- cnt + 1
    }
    
    result[idx] <- cnt
  }
  
  result
}

need_name <- function(cnt) {
  result <- logical(length(cnt))
  for(idx in seq_along(cnt)){
     if(cnt[idx] == 0){
       if(idx == length(cnt)){
         result[idx] <- FALSE
         break
       }
       
       result[idx] <- (cnt[idx + 1] != 0)
     } else{
       result[idx] <- TRUE
     }
  }
  
  result
}

running_count <- function(v) {
  cnt <- 0
  flag <- FALSE
  result <- integer(length(v))
  for(idx in seq_along(v)){
    if(v[idx]) {
      
      if(!flag) {
        cnt <- cnt + 1
        flag <- !flag
      }
      
      result[idx] <- cnt
    } else{
      result[idx] <- 0
      flag <- FALSE
    }
  }
  
  result
}


test %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(
    duration = date - lag(date),   # --- Compute durations
    is_first = duration != 1       # --- Check if it is the first day of a protest
  ) %>%
  replace_na(list(is_first = TRUE)) %>%  # --- No more NAs
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(
    cnt = event_count(is_first),  # --- How many days does this event have?
    need_name = need_name(cnt)    # --- Should we name this event?
  ) %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(
    name_number = running_count(need_name)  # --- What's the event count?
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    name = paste0(state, ".", name_number),  # ---- Create names
    cumulative = cnt + 1  # --- Start counting from one instead of zero
  ) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(
    duration = max(duration)  # --- Calc total duration
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(  # --- Adding the NAs back
    name = if_else(name_number == 0, NA_character_, name),
    duration = if_else(name_number == 0, NA_integer_, as.integer(duration)),
    cumulative = if_else(name_number == 0, NA_integer_, as.integer(cumulative)),
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table::rleid` is useful here to create run lengths based on the condition if `days_last == 1` or `days_next == 1` (ie sequential dates). If you want different event lengths you can edit that condition.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

test %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(state) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(days_last = c(NA, diff(date)),
                days_next = as.numeric(lead(date) - date),
                name = paste0(state, ".", data.table::rleid(days_last == 1 | days_next == 1))) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(sequence = case_when(
    n() == 1 ~ "Not Linked",
    row_number() == 1 ~ "First day",
    n() == row_number() ~ "Last day",
    T ~ "Ongoing"),
  duration = n(),
  cumulative = seq_along(name)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
 state      date       days_last days_next name         sequence   duration cumulative
   <chr>      <date>         <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        <chr>         <int>      <int>
 1 Washington 2021-01-01        NA         2 Washington.1 Not Linked        1          1
 2 Washington 2021-01-03         2         1 Washington.2 First day         2          1
 3 Washington 2021-01-04         1         6 Washington.2 Last day          2          2
 4 Washington 2021-01-10         6         5 Washington.3 Not Linked        1          1
 5 Washington 2021-01-15         5         1 Washington.4 First day         5          1
 6 Washington 2021-01-16         1         1 Washington.4 Ongoing           5          2
 7 Washington 2021-01-17         1         1 Washington.4 Ongoing           5          3
 8 Washington 2021-01-18         1         1 Washington.4 Ongoing           5          4
 9 Washington 2021-01-19         1         9 Washington.4 Last day          5          5
10 Washington 2021-01-28         9        NA Washington.5 Not Linked        1          1
11 Idaho      2021-01-12        NA         1 Idaho.1      First day         3          1
12 Idaho      2021-01-13         1         1 Idaho.1      Ongoing           3          2
13 Idaho      2021-01-14         1        18 Idaho.1      Last day          3          3
14 Idaho      2021-02-01        18         2 Idaho.2      Not Linked        1          1
15 Idaho      2021-02-03         2         1 Idaho.3      First day         3          1
16 Idaho      2021-02-04         1         1 Idaho.3      Ongoing           3          2
17 Idaho      2021-02-05         1         3 Idaho.3      Last day          3          3
18 Idaho      2021-02-08         3         2 Idaho.4      First day         2          1
19 Idaho      2021-02-10         2         4 Idaho.4      Last day          2          2
20 Idaho      2021-02-14         4        NA Idaho.5      Not Linked        1          1
```

If need by you can use the `NA` in the `days_last` column to `NA` values in other rows.

---

> Side question: Why is test$sequence[11] an NA and not "First day"?

Generally, in R `NA` propagates, meaning if `NA` is part of the evaluation then normally `NA` is returned. When you define `sequence` your first `ifelse` condition is `link_last == 0 & link_next == 1`. On row 11, `link_last = NA` and `link_next = 1`. So what you're evaluating is:

```
NA == 0 & 1 == 1
[1] NA
```

Instead your nested condition should come first. How your `ifelse` is currently written that nested condition is *not* being evaluated:

```
is.na(NA) & 1 == 1
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is super helpful - particularly the response to my final question. Thank you so much, @LMc!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach.

```r
library(data.table)

# Convert from data.frame to data.table
setDT(test)

# Subset the variables.
test2 <- test[, .(state, date, days_last = as.numeric(days_last), 
                  days_next = as.numeric(days_next), sequence)]

# Code
test2[, name := paste0(state, '.', rleid(days_last == 1 | days_next == 1)),
     by = state][
       , ':='(duration = .N,
              cumulative = seq(1:.N)),
       by = name
     ][, c('days_next', 'days_last'):=NULL] # Removing these variables. Feel free to add back!

# Reorder the variables
test2 <- setcolorder(test2, c('state', 'name', 'date', 
                              'sequence', 'duration', 
                              'cumulative'))
# Print first 15 rows
print(test2[1:15,])

#>          state         name       date   sequence duration cumulative
#>  1: Washington Washington.1 2021-01-01       <NA>        1          1
#>  2: Washington Washington.2 2021-01-03  First day        2          1
#>  3: Washington Washington.2 2021-01-04   Last day        2          2
#>  4: Washington Washington.3 2021-01-10 Not linked        1          1
#>  5: Washington Washington.4 2021-01-15  First day        5          1
#>  6: Washington Washington.4 2021-01-16    Ongoing        5          2
#>  7: Washington Washington.4 2021-01-17    Ongoing        5          3
#>  8: Washington Washington.4 2021-01-18    Ongoing        5          4
#>  9: Washington Washington.4 2021-01-19   Last day        5          5
#> 10: Washington Washington.5 2021-01-28       <NA>        1          1
#> 11:      Idaho      Idaho.1 2021-01-12       <NA>        3          1
#> 12:      Idaho      Idaho.1 2021-01-13    Ongoing        3          2
#> 13:      Idaho      Idaho.1 2021-01-14   Last day        3          3
#> 14:      Idaho      Idaho.2 2021-02-01 Not linked        1          1
#> 15:      Idaho      Idaho.3 2021-02-03  First day        3          1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>